# SSAS cube has no data

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, ssas, m2m

I was making new enhancements to SSAS cube and in the process have 'broken' the cube. Meanwhile, I have deleted all the new dimensions and facts I had added from DSV. Saved and processed dimensions and cube few times with no luck. :(

1. I have checked all the partitions are intact. Running the partition queries returns data as expected.

2.'Calculated' is present in the script.

3 Click on dimension -> Explore data...data is present in all dimensions as well as fact tables.

In the cube designer when I check 'Browser' tab and drag measures, no data is seen. Chosing both dimensions and measures yield no data as well. It is basically empty.

How can I fix this? How to use SQL server profiler to analyze the number of reads/writes? I tried but I didnt see any 'read' or write'columns.

I am using SQL SERVER 2008R2.

Thanks. Kindly requesting some help.

--SK

Comment: What happens if you do a full process of the Analysis Services database? Does that repair the state?

Comment: @FrankPl, Did that but no change. I did run MDX select statements in the scripts to check if there is any data at all in the cube. The result was all 'NULL'. I could see the dimension values but not the measures. I did every check on all the properties for each measure, everything seems to be right there.                                       What is the way to debug a SSAS cube? is rebuilding the only way? I got this cube from someone else and I have enhanced a bit of this and that on this from the past 6 months. Thanks!

Comment: Are there possibly any permission restrictions for the user that you use? Check the roles that are configured. I would try to connect with a user having full administrative access. Furthermore, you could try to comment out the complete calculation script, except for the one line that states `CALCULATE;` and redeploy (no need to re-process the cube after this change). Does that help?

Comment: I don't see 'Deploy' option at all!!! Under Build-> Process is all I see!! I need to ask permission to be able to deploy right? I need to talk to the IT desk to grant me admin rights?Or how exactly should I phrase this as? This could lead me to the solution!                                                        What is the difference between Deploy and Process?I thought that from my reading in last 2-3 days that once you deploy the project, you only need to process for the changes to take affect. Build, Deploy,process-that's the order right?

Comment: Btw, I just checked and found out that I ahev admin rights. I ahve the following permissions -Full control, process database, read definition. Doesn't it seem strange then that I don't see deploy option at all even though I am an admin?

Comment: If you have the project open in BIDS, in Solution Explorer, right-click on the project node, select the bottom entry "Properties", and then "Deployment". Check/change the entries for server and database, and close this dialog with OK. Then again do a right click on the project node and select deploy.

Comment: I suspect you have used Visual Studio to directly open the Analysis Services Database. You can confirm this by viewing the Properties for the Project node - this node will not show any Properties. In this scenario, your changes are immediately deployed when you Save.

Comment: Thanks, Mike and Frank for all your help. Since I am only hitting dead end with anything that I have tried. I am building a new cube all over again. I have a new problem now. I have **sales_fact**->**reportperiod dim**. Currency_fact-> **reportperiod dim** and currency_fact -> **dim_currency**. Under 'Dimension usage' -Sales_fact is marked to have M2M with dim_currency through intermediate table currency_fact. Dim_currency has one attribute currency_code with properties **Isaggregatable** = 'False', *Default_member*=[Currency].[Currency Code].[EUR].Measure properties  -sum, visibleare checked.

Comment: When I try to create aggregations for sales_fact, this is the error I see - Errors in the aggregation designer. The 'Currency' dimension has no attribute for the aggregation design.  The server cannot design aggregations when this attribute is missing. However, in the Production cube, I can see that partitions and aggregations have been successfully designed for this fact table. From my reading I understand that when there is a M2M relationship with intermediate table, aggregations are not possible. But the prod system seems to have aggregation built for this measure.Thanks.

Comment: @SKa If you have no problems, write a new question. Stackoverflow is not a discussion board, but a question and answers site.

Comment: I found the issue.I discovered that when I had currency filter in my XL pivot table with all the other currencies selected except Euros, everything appeared fine. But the moment I selected Euros from the list, data disappeared. So, the prob had to be with currency as I suspected  even in the beginning. I studied about M2M relationships and how to handle reporting in diff currencies. In the dimension usage tab the 'relationship' Direct Slice property had to be set to Currency.EUR. This property was somehow empty. M2Mrelationships - look for hidden tables & direct slice property in dim usage tab